# Simulation and sampling

Tags: simulation

I am working on a question which involves an experiment to determine relationship between IQ level and subject.
He models the distribution of scores as a mixture of 2 normal distributions.
Then he asked:

> If you wished to use samples from a single normal distribution and
>   standard uniform random variables, which method might you use to
>   simulate from this distribution.

My queries are as follows:

1. What is meant by 'simulate from this distribution'?
2. Does he mean to model the distribution using a normal and a standard uniform distribution instead of 2 normal distributions?
3. When he says 'model the distribution of scores as a mixture if 2 normal distributions', does he mean that the pdf of the score is a joint distribution with the 2 normal distributions?
4. What would he use samples from a single normal distribution and standard uniform random variables for?